# Convert currency to decimal via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a currency format like this **Rp 25.100.000,00**

I want to convert this format to decimal **25100000.00**

I try to do this but it's seems not working

```
var number = Number(data[9].replace(/[^0-9,-]+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can breakdown the problem in simple steps

1. Remove all the non digit except `,` character ( You can add more characters here in character class which you don’t want to be replaced )
2. replace `,` by `.`

```js
let currencyFormatter = str => str.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')
                                  .replace(/,/g, '.')

console.log(currencyFormatter("Rp 25.100.000,00"))
```

Comment: It's a nice way thankyou for your answer mr. Code Maniac